# What is the difference between a hollow (sphere/cylinder) and a shell (cylinder/sphere)?

Tags: terminology, geometry

First of all, it was hard to "tag" this question !
Anyways, 
I see some contradictions in what a shell or a hollow cylinder is in some sources in the internet based on some figures they show.

I tried to pull out some formal-abstract- linguistic (although it is not in our interest but I did that because I could not find any formal order-based definition in physics)
Shell meaning: "2. Something resembling or having the form of a shell, especially:
a. An external, usually hard, protective or enclosing case or cover.
b. A framework or exterior, as of a building.
c. A thin layer of pastry.
d. The external part of the ear." 
source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shell

Notice: "Something resembling or having the form of a shell" as if someone defines water, after great work, as simply... water!!

Hollow: "1. having a hole, cavity, or space within; not solid" 
same source as above.

In fact, if you google about it, it is very very very very hard to see any formal scientific based definition or any satisfactory explanations of these spherical shells/ shell cylinders ...etc

So, I am not pretending that I do not know any thing about them but I always see many contradictions. As examples: Some people say that shell cylinder is the like a solid cylinder in which some of it is taken out BUT not from where r=0. Rather it is taken out from where r=6 units for example. So, the if the inner radius is a, r < a is NOT space but b>r>a it is where b is the outer one. However, other sources say no: it is space when r < a and not space when r>a. Similar contradictions happened for the hollow ones.

So, the problem is not necessarily "what are they?" but rather what is the formal definition of each (with avoiding the "general conventions" here)!
Note: I did not search yet that much about spheres but I included it in this question just in case if the definition of "shell" or "hollow" is dependent/independent on the physical structure that is associated with. So, I am looking for some kind of definition that is related to physics rather than just a mere word!!!!!

Comment: Wouldn't this be better served by posting it to "I don't like the way you use words, so let me tell you how I want you to use them".stackexchange.com?

Comment: It is not a matter of likeness. It is a matter of "What is the difference between a hollow (sphere/cylinder) and a shell (cylinder/sphere)?". So, up to now 2 responses say that there is no a "formal" definition for each term. Okay, let us wait.

Comment: If that is not obvious to you, and you don't like any of the answers given to you, the most likely explanation is that you don't want an answer.

Comment: I am not sure how you are most likely 100% sure that such formal definitions do not exist! You just want for me to give it up.

Comment: I am merely here to see how many down votes you are getting. So far you are doing very well in that department. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose an electrical wire, if you take out everything that is present inside the covering, you get a shell, but if you take out the central wire , you get a hollow cylinder.
According to me, shell is just the covering. Let r1 be the inner radius amd r2 be outer radius.
For a shell, r2-r1 tends to zero (in theory) whereas for a hollow sphere r2-r1 is more than 0 and less than r2.

Note: This is my understanding of 'hollow' and 'shell'. There may be some other possible explanations.

Comment: "According to you"? I am really not against that but you are saying that these definitions are relative!

Comment: You should've quoted "According to me" And I was just trying to say that it can be explained in many other ways. I should've typed "One possible way to explain this " and stuff.

Comment: That was a mistake sorry. I was angry at your sentence. But this flexibility of defining these terms in science is problematic. We are like saying you can define a square in many ways.

Comment: A Square is a rectangle in hich the length and the breadth are of same size. It is a rhombus which one of the angles is a right angle. Or it is a rhombus in which diagonals are of equal length. Or it is a regular polygon of 4 sides. No matter how we define it, unless there is any flaw or difference between two definitions, All of them are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, a true "shell" does not exist but is simply a mathematical approximation. For a sphere, we could define it to be the collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$. This forms a surface of "infintesimal" thickness, thus a shell. In general, this is how one defines shells.

Comment: I would call this one a hollow sphere! Unless if you agree that shell=hollow in "reality". I do not agree with this anyways!

Comment: Usually they mean the same thing. But it depends on context. A hollow sphere can refer to what I mentioned as well as a spherical shell. A hollow sphere can also refer to a sphere with finite thickness as well is a spherical shell. One just needs to specify. You are getting caught up in semantics

Comment: What would you call the shell sphere (based on your definition) that has inside: a solid sphere centered at the center of "the outer .. shell" sphere ?

Comment: Technically that is called a ball in mathematical jargon